# Filter a json by values

Tags: python, json

I have this code

```
import json,urllib2
def Trade(item):
    url = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://api.warframe.market/v1/items/'+item+'/orders')).read())
    primo = url["payload"]
    secondo = primo["orders"]
    prezzi = []
    for tata in secondo:
        price = tata["platinum"]
        prezzi.append(price)
    print sorted(prezzi,key=int)
```

I get an ordered DESC list, but i need to filter it by "status", in url["payload"]["orders"]["user"]["status"].

I'm kinda new with json parsing, and I need to define sublevels with an integer, but I need to parse the whole json to order "price" DESC by online status of user.

What can I do?

Here is an example of my JSON data: https://api.warframe.market/v1/items/primed_chamber/orders

Comment: Please try to include one sample of the JSON data you want to parse instead of a link. This makes the question much more readable. Please have a look at the guide [How to provide a Minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well according to your question(which is not much clear) but as far i understand you need the "price" list of online users, and "price" means platinum value here in your json data. So to do this.

**Try this:**

```
import json

filedata = open('jsondata.txt', 'r')
jsondata = json.load(filedata)

ingame_users_platinum = []
offline_users_platinum = []

for i in jsondata['payload']['orders']:
    if i['user']['status'] == 'offline':
        offline_users_platinum.append(i['platinum'])
    elif i['user']['status'] == 'ingame':
        ingame_users_platinum.append(i['platinum'])

print("Price/Platinum of ingame users: \n", ingame_users_platinum)
print("Price/Platinum of offline users: \n", offline_users_platinum)
```

**This will give you output like this:**

```
Price/Platinum of ingame users: 
 [35000, 70000, 2000, 69, 10, 75000, 500, 1000, 100, 500]
Price/Platinum of offline users: 
 [30000, 28282, 10000, 3200, 1, 2000, 25, 666, 55000, 10000, 2000, 30, 25000, 4200, 10, 20000, 100, 1000, 45000, 20000, 1000, 4500, 300, 20000, 20000, 20000, 50000, 66666, 6666, 200, 200, 5000, 50000, 11000, 8, 100, 500, 50, 4500, 66000, 69000, 5, 20, 150, 400, 42, 5, 20000, 25000, 36000, 69, 10, 1000, 1, 450, 1, 40000, 1000, 120, 68000, 100, 1, 20000, 322, 1, 1, 60000, 50000, 53000, 5, 5000, 1, 1000, 1, 1, 100, 8000, 10000, 40000, 5000, 100, 1, 1, 200, 20, 1, 500, 46, 500, 1, 40000, 20, 133337, 911, 188888, 10000, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30000, 200, 40000, 100000, 90000, 199999, 1, 10, 1, 150]
```

**To sort these list in desc:**
Do This:

```
ingame_users_platinum.sort(key=int, reverse=True)   # For sorted in desc
offline_users_platinum.sort(key=int, reverse=True)  # For sorted in desc
```

Then print them again to get output. **Like This:**

```
Price/Platinum of ingame users: 
 [75000, 70000, 35000, 2000, 1000, 500, 500, 100, 69, 10]
Price/Platinum of offline users: 
 [199999, 188888, 133337, 100000, 90000, 69000, 68000, 66666, 66000, 60000, 55000, 53000, 50000, 50000, 50000, 45000, 40000, 40000, 40000, 40000, 36000, 30000, 30000, 28282, 25000, 25000, 20000, 20000, 20000, 20000, 20000, 20000, 20000, 11000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 8000, 6666, 5000, 5000, 5000, 4500, 4500, 4200, 3200, 2000, 2000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 911, 666, 500, 500, 500, 450, 400, 322, 300, 200, 200, 200, 200, 150, 150, 120, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 69, 50, 46, 42, 30, 25, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 8, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Hope This will help you! :)

Comment: Indeed! many thanks for your complete answer! totally solved my problem !! Thanks again!